# Neo4J - Get filtered results based on some property that does not exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There are `product`s that can have multiple `ProductImage`s. I want to fetch a product (given its ID) and its associated images based on an image property `isUseful`. Only those images should be fetched which do not have the `isUseful` property available. I have this query:

```
MATCH (product:Product)
      WHERE product.id = $productId    
      RETURN product{
        .*,
        images: [(product)<-[:BELONGSTO]-(image:ProductImage {isUseful: null}) | image{.*}]
}
```

This query does not return any results. But there are records in the database. Please note that I can only change what is written inside the `return` block. Nothing else can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use equality on null, you need to use `IS NULL`. Please check out the documentation here:

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/working-with-null/

As such, you need to add a WHERE clause to your pattern comprehension to get the results you want:

```
[(product)<-[:BELONGSTO]-(image:ProductImage) WHERE image.isUseful IS NULL | image{.*}]
```